# Potential Concerns in Stopping Meteor Ungracefully

Tags: meteor

Just getting into Meteor, which by many accounts seems like a great project. One potential issue (which it may not be) is there doesn't seem to be a `meteor stop` or another programmatic way to shut down meteor gracefully. *Please let me know if I am wrong about this!*

Are there potential concerns about maintaining database integrity (for example), if we interrupt the process using `CTRL-C` or shutting it down via an Activity Monitor? And are there steps we can take to reduce or eliminate such issues?

**Caveat**: I recognize the above questions are somewhat vague, and I understand that this is usually considered harmful on Stack, but I hope they are still answerable ones.

Thanks,

Comment: +1 Interesting question, one that never crossed my mind, but one that probably should have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like there is a cleanup which takes place before the process is terminated (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/tools/cleanup.js).

The first signal sent is `SIGINT` which is a polite way to ask the process to shut down (and give it time to finish its last running thread)

With database integrity, the mongod process also tries to clean itself up before it shuts down & it has a recovery mechanism (from the journal files) on a quick recovery while restarting if forced to shutdown.

That being said, in the middle of a longer running thread I'm not too sure if it's allowed to finish or its killed immediately. But meteor does attempt to give it a chance to have a graceful termination at first, and then escalates it to a `SIGHUP` then finally a `SIGTERM` (which is still a graceful termination signal). At no point does meteor force or send a SIGKILL or SIGSTOP.

So meteor apps should be safe from Ctrl+C termination. With activity monitor termination it depends on what type of signal its sent (i.e Force Quit or just Quit)

Comment: Thanks for linking to the specific cleanup.js it also looks like there is an mongo-exit-codes.js file. I wonder if it could be leveraged to offer some check on the database state.

Answer (score 0):

So to add some closure to this, if your mongodb is externally managed, i.e. on a deployment production server meteor doesn't stop it as mongo-runner.js notes:

```
// Since it is externally managed, asking it to actually stop would be
// impolite, so our stoppable handle is a noop
if (process.env.MONGO_URL) {
launch_callback();
return handle;
}
```

Comment: Additionally on the server-side javascript in the `Meteor.publish()` function you will want want to call `_this_.onStop(function(){ [your_handle].stop});`